# adf task flows in page fragments

Tags: oracle-adf, regions, adf-task-flow, page-fragments

I have a main page (main.jsff) where the header, footer and the menu is the same for all pages. which changes every navigation is the region.
The other pages I have (.jsff) correspond to fields of research and a table of detail. In search fields (inputText) added a autosugestbehavior. However when I am in one of the pages, eg bookingSearch.jsff and test to see if the autosuggest works it changes the page after you enter a letter.
Always go to the main page.
I checked the code (bookingSearch.java) and not have anything to point to another page. I think the problem is in the tasks flows.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Tell us your Jdev version, please! How have you implemented the auto suggest? Please describe your use case in more detail.

Comment: Hello Timo,

My version Jdev is 11.1.2.4.0 g Release 2.

Comment: I have the input text and in there i add the component autoSuggestBehavior.
In the SuggestedItems i insert the name of method created. after in nameofpage.java i create the methods.